# How to differentiate between no database records and no filtered database records in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

What's the best approach to differentiate between no database records and no filtered database records? I want to hide a search field when there are no database records, but show it when there are database records but none after the filter. Is there an easy and efficient way to just tag on an unfiltered count to use in my if statement?

```
Contact::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
        ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
        ->orWhereHas('tags', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('title', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%');
        });
})
    ->with('tags')
    ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
    ->paginate(10)
```

Comment: This is almost more related to the frontend, can you show us how you are planning on doing that?

Comment: I guess I can put all my search variables in a querystring and just check if’s set instead of running multiple queries.

Comment: @SeaBass as the user @mrhn said, you should pass a variable to the view telling it if there is any data (a simple `Contact::exists()` should work, never tried that) and then use the normal filter in your front end (maybe API/AJAX). It is that easy.

Comment: Yes, but I realized that I can just check if the filter is set on the front end and save a db query with exist. Not that it’s a very heavy query.

Comment: If you figured it out, please add what solved it, if anyone else in the feature finds this post and wants to know the solution